# gnuplot to python: splot pm3d like in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gnuplot

I have data file something like

```
x1 y1 z11
x1 y2 z12
... 
x1 yn z1n
...
xn yn-1 znn-1
xn yn znn
```

In gnuplot I was using the following to produce heatmap

```
splot "file.txt" u 1:2:(log(\$3)) w pm3d notitle
```

How can I produce similar thing in python?

Comment: You can use a gnuplot wrapper. I like [this one](https://github.com/mzechmeister/python/wiki/gplot.py)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. Do you want generate a plot using gnuplot via Python or do you want to generate a plot using matplotlib in Python?